# data.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

I've that very simple code

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include 'config.php';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT str_data ,occasione FROM Evento");

$arraydata = array();
$arraynome = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
   $arraydata[] = date("m-d-Y", $row['str_data']);
   $arraynome[] = $row['occasione'];
}

$datanome = array_combine($arraydata, $arraynome);
echo json_encode($datanome);
?>
```

but when i use the chrome console on that website
http://www.ldida.altervista.org/calendario/index2.html
it gives

```
data.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

why?

Comment: Try `include('config.php');`

Comment: Doesn 't fix the problem.This is what the browser see of my data.php file http://www.ldida.altervista.org/calendario/js/data.php

Answer (score 1):

You are including data.php as type **text/javascript**.
Therefore your browser tries to parse it as javascript.
The output of data.php is:

```
{"04-20-2016":"Compleanno","05-14-2016":"Compleanno","05-03-2016":"Battesimo"}
```

This is no valid javascript, therefore the error. This is not a php error but a javascript parsing error.

Comment: but if i delete the 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/data.php"></script> 
string on my index2.html page the F12 > NETWORK will not load the js/data.php. How can i fix it?

Comment: @Naaku you need to fetch that file with ajax.

Comment: @jcubic I already use that code 
caldata: function() {
      $.get("js/data.php")
      .done(function(data) {
      $calendar.setData(data);
      })
      .fail(function() {
       console.log('failed')
      });
      return [];
      },
but the page doesn't load the data.php file, why?

Comment: @Naaku you are passing a function to `caldata` which accepts a object. You should put your ajax call outside the calendario object initialization.

Comment: @AndreasScheibleger i should put that code    $function() {
       $.get("js/data.php")
       .done(function(data))
       .fail(function() {
        console.log('failed')
       });
       return [];
       } before the calendario function and then what i have to write there "caldata: ???," , thank you.

Comment: @Naaku: i don't know that library. According to documentation you can initialize calldata to `null` and later set the calendar data using `setData`. Therefore doing the ajax call after calendario initialization should work.

Comment: @Andreas Scheibleger mh.. and i inizialize the caldata just doing caldata : null and then using the code to get the data from the PHP file after the calendar script ?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/data.php"></script>` from your HTML/source code.

You're calling it via jQuery - you don't need to include it in the page itself.

You're also including it as text/javascript, which it is not.

Comment: I've tryed that but if i get rid of that code when i go into F12 > NETWORK the js/data.php file will not get loaded. why?